# How to decide what goes on stack?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, heap-memory, stack-memory

Say I have a C++ class called MainComponent and it has a few classes inside of it: WindowClass, InputClass, GameClass. The main function is setup like so:

```
int main()
{
    MainComponent app;
    app.start(); // Initializes the MainComponent class, opens window, starts game and all that.

    return 0;
}
```

The MainComponent class is expected to possibly get very big because of included objects of GameClass and such. Should MainComponent app be dynamically allocated with new? or should I allocate the GameClass objects with new inside the MainComponent class? or is it just fine to leave it on the stack as long as it runs fine or what?

Comment: If your MainComponent is really too big, you'll get a nice stack**overflow**

Comment: There is no reason for `MainComponent` to get really big just because it contains lots of things. If it allocates those things from the free store (heap) it can remain fairly small itself. And that goes for things it contains too. You only need to allocate large data arrays from the free-store (heap), not the class objects that manage them (`MainComponent, GameClass, WindowBits...`). Use `STL` containers and they will do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what 'big' means. [This link](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt) shows the default stack size limits for some OSes. You'll want to make sure that the size `MainComponent` allocates on the stack is well below any of these numbers.

Further, if there are certain things being dynamically created, or certain arrays/assets that are too large, which fall under `MainComponent` or another struct that is below `MainComponent`, then you can always heap-allocate that struct/array/class while still keeping MainComponent itself on the stack.

Conceptually, keeping `MainComponent` on the stack makes more sense as its lifecycle is being modeled exactly by its scope in the `main` function.

To answer your more general question, *How to decide what goes on the stack?*, consider three aspects:

1. **Ownership**. Is the ownership of a particular data structure clear? Does it explicitly belong to a particular function (and its descendants), or a particular struct/class and can be modeled with RAII?
2. **Lifecycle**. Is the particular data structure expected to exist within a timeline that closely resembles a lifetime of the class that created it, or the function that created it? What is the scope?
3. **Is the size known at compile-time?**  This comes up when allocating arrays of a variable size. This is the case with many STL containers. In that case, the basic struct/class includes a few things on the stack and then maintains pointers to heap-allocated structures.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> MainComponent class is expected to possibly get very big because of
>   included objects of GameClass

object size is constant. for example: empty `std::string` has the same `sizeof` as very long `std::string`, it is the same for any object.

the `sizeof(object)` is the only bytes it take on the stack. all the rest anyway goes to the heap.

so if you reach to stack limits and got stack overflow exceptions, then you should try to move some objects to heap. or if it is a single object (like your `MainComponent` class appear to be), you can also use the `singleton` pattern, or just declare it as `static`, to remove it from the stack to other segments of memory.